# Initialise a double array to a non-zero value

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am doing the following:

```
double dVar[100] = { 0.1 };
```

But when I debug, it only puts 0.1 to dVar[0] and rest are all 0.0;

I just thought to avoid a for loop.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But when I debug, it only puts 0.1 to dVar[0] and rest are all 0.0;

This is the expected behaviour. If the initializer contains less elements than the aggregate (the array) then [value-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) is performed on the remaining elements, which in this case sets them to zero.

While not initialization, to avoid explicitly hand-coding a loop use [`std::fill()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill):

```
double dVar[100];
std::fill(std::begin(dVar), std::end(dVar), 0.1);
```

As suggested by [Olaf Dietsche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1741542/olaf-dietsche) in his answer, changing from an array to a `std::vector<double>` would permit initialization to a value other than zero. If the fact that the `std::vector` can change size is unappealling and your compiler has some c++14 features you may want to consider using [`std::dynarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray). It is not possible to change the number of elements in a `dynarray` and all elements can be assigned a value other than zero at initialization, similar to `std::vector`:

```
std::dynarray<double> dVar(100, 0.1);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is expected behaviour. If you don't initialize all elements of the array explicitly, they will be automatically set to zero.

To initialize all elements to `0.1`, you can use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) and use a constructor with explicit initialization

```
std::vector dVar(100, 0.1);
```

This will create a vector with 100 elements, all set to 0.1.